# nomenclature hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation, nomenclature

I'm using \makenomenclature and \printnomenclature.. I have searched since yesterday for solution with nomenclature, but found nothing. Do anybody have a solution? I don't want do it with glossary, because the documentclasse is book and I have a lot of tex files. When I use glossary, I have to search every word in nomenclatur in many tex files.

I have a problem. My nomenclature shows like this for example

```
   AAAA      AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    
   BBBB      BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
   number angelsperunitz The number of angels per unit are
```

This is the nomenclaturecode..

```
   \nomenclature{number angelsperunitz }{The number of angels per unit area}
```

I want it shows like this, because the acronym is too long and I want this in the next line. How can I do this? I use hyphenation without success.

```
    AAAA         AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
    BBBB         BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
    number angelsp-
    erunitz The number of angels per unit are
```

Here is the code..

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}

\nomenclature{AAAA}{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}%
\nomenclature{BBBB}{BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB}%
\nomenclature{number angelsperunitz}{The number of angels per unit are}%


\backmatter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
\printnomenclature[2.8 cm]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to play with?

Comment: @egreg I put the code. I do something different, like this \printnomenclature[4.2 cm]. This is not was I want but it looks better as before.

Answer (score 3):

Redefine `\nomlabel` to use a `\parbox[b]` and reset `\nomlabelwidth`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{%
  \parbox[b]{\nomlabelwidth}{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}#1}%
}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{2.5cm}

\makenomenclature
\begin{document}

\nomenclature{AAAA}{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}%
\nomenclature{BBBB}{BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB}%
\nomenclature{number angelsperunitz}{The number of angels per unit are}%

Do something!

\backmatter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I have math expressions like `$f(a,b,c,d,...)$` which cannot be wrapped...

Comment: @Robinaut TeX will never wrap formulas after a comma, which in case of `$f(a,b,c,d)$ would make no sense.

Comment: So what can I do if the symbol cannot be line-wrapped in `parbox{}`?

Comment: @Robinaut Use a width sufficient to contain the symbols.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similiar problem, but I was using the glossaries package. [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/dYpS26K1K5k) thread in comp.text.tex gave me a working solution:

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,]{glossaries} % make a separate list of
acronyms
\usepackage{glossary-tree}

\setlength{\glslistdottedwidth}{4cm}

\newglossarystyle{altlistdotted}%
{%
   \glossarystyle{tree}%
   \renewcommand{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
     \hangindent0pt\relax
     \parindent0pt\relax
     \makebox[\glslistdottedwidth][l]%
     {%
       \glsentryitem{##1}\textbf{\glstarget{##1}{##2}}%
       \unskip\leaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill\strut
     }%
     \parbox[t]{\linewidth-\glslistdottedwidth}{##3}\par}%
}

\glossarystyle{altlistdotted}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{Acronym}{Acronym}{Explanation of an acronym}
  \newacronym{short}{short}{This is only short}
  \newacronym{long}{long}{This explanation is longer, so you get a line break here}
  \newacronym{superlong}{superlong}{This explanation is so long, that it is even long than the long example}
  \glsaddall
\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there really no more solution?